# Generating a Grid of NSTextField Objects From NSDictionary Items

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm trying to create an vocabulary study application using Obj-C and the Cocoa frameworks. I have about two week's experience in both areas and have reached an edge of my current knowledge.

Here's where I'm stuck. When I press a checkbox, a corresponding plist is loaded into memory as an NSDictionary. I want to generate a "Label: Textfield" pair for each key:value pair, where the Label is the key. When the text typed into the Textfield matches the key's value, I want the Label's text to turn green.

So how would I generate this grid, and once generated, how would I make the text green upon correct input?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I want to generate a "Label: Textfield" pair for each key:value pair, where the Label is the key. When the text typed into the Textfield matches the key's value, I want the Label's text to turn green.
>
> So how would I generate this grid, …

[NSForm.](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSForm_Class/)

> … and once generated, how would I make the text green upon correct input?

[Set the relevant form cell's title](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFormCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFormCell/setAttributedTitle:) to an [attributed string](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/) with the key [in green](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAttributedString_AppKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSForegroundColorAttributeName).

Comment: So do I just allocate an NSForm and then use the addEntry for each item in the dictionary? How does IB know how to draw the grid?

Comment: IB doesn't draw the grid in your application; IB is a separate application. Views draw themselves, and NSForm is one of the many view classes. I would suggest creating the NSForm object yourself (in code, not in IB) since you're not going to have it pre-filled with values. See the View Programming Guide for more info: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/